# EXCEL If function, please guide me...?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I have a table which consists of set of data, say `2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16`

I want to create a program in which one cell I input, the other cell I show the output.

For Example:

If I key in a value of 3 in the input cell, the excel will respond something like "there's no 3. THe values suitable are 2 and 4" in the output cell.

If I key in a value of 4 in the input cell, the excel will respond a value of 4 in the output cell.

I'm thinkg of If function. I14 is the input cell. D7 until D14 is the cell where the data locate.

If I14 is the same as any value in the data, the output will show the value. If it is not the same....I'm stuck.

```
=IF(I14=$D$7:$D$14,$D$7:$D$14,I14)
```

please help me!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the Data Validation tool.

1. Select the cell you want to have this validation, in your case, select cell `I27`.
2. Go to the "Data" tab, click the "Data Validation" button and use those options:

   [image]

   The source is where the valid list is, in your case `$D$7:$D$14`. You can also uncheck the dropdown if you want.
3. You can then choose the warning you need:

   [image]

Comment: That's not what I wanted. Not drop down list.

Comment: I want something like the while and if statement in Matlab.

Comment: @JackieNina You can opt not to have a dropdown as I told you in my answer. I don't know how it is in Matlab, but uncheck "In-cell dropdown" in the first picture next to "List".